# How can I optimize this further?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has approx. 121,246,211 rows. The records are simple page impression information.

Here is the schema:

```
create table stat_page
(
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  pageId int not null,
  timestamp int not null
)
  collate = utf8_unicode_ci;

create index pageIdIndex
  on stat_page (pageId);

create index timestampIndex
  on stat_page (timestamp);
```

This query takes 15 seconds:

```
select count(*)
from stat_page
where `timestamp` > 1543622400;
```

This query takes nearly 7 minutes:

```
select count(*)
from stat_page
where `timestamp` > 1543622400
and pageId = 87;
```

I thought I indexed the right things; is the table just too large? Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to get information from this table faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following index will improve the performance of that query:

```
create index ix1 on stat_page (pageId, timestamp);
```

This query benefits of this "composite" index.

Comment: @DStanley I think switching the order of the columns will improve the other query but not this one. This query has an equality (`=`) for the column `pageId`, that should greatly benefit of this column to be placed in first place.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, I don't know why I did not think of that. Cheers.